# Create/change repository level GHA variable

Tags: github-actions

I have a counter stored as a repository variable.
I'd like to increment it via a GitHub action

I've tried a few variations of this, but this gives a syntax error:  `invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".MY_COUNTER + 1 ")`

```bash
echo "Useful context info"
echo "==================="
echo ""
echo "MY_COUNTER: ${{ vars.MY_COUNTER }}"
echo "${{ vars.MY_COUNTER + 1 }}" >> $vars.MY_COUNTER
echo "MY_COUNTER: ${{ vars.MY_COUNTER }}"
```

How can I create/update a repository level variable at runtime in GitHub Actions?

Answer (score 0):

- [Expressions](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/expressions#operators) don't provide arithmetic operators; to increment a value, you'd have to use shell commands, like

  ```yaml
  - env:
      counter: ${{ vars.MY_COUNTER }}
    run: |
      echo "$counter"        # Example: 1
      echo "$((++counter))"  # Example: 2
  ```

  This actually increments the value of `$counter` going forward.
- There's no mechanism to update an organization or repository variable similar to [environment files](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#environment-files) for environment variables or output parameters. You can use the [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/variables?apiVersion=2022-11-28#update-a-repository-variable) for this, or even more conveniently, the [built-in command from the GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_variable_set):

  ```bash
  gh variable set MY_COUNTER --body '123'
  ```

  This operates on the current repository by default. You can indicate another repository explicitly, see below.

Combining these two, here's a run step that increments a repository variable:

```yaml
- name: Increment counter
  env:
    counter: ${{ vars.MY_COUNTER }}
  run: |
    gh variable set MY_COUNTER --body "$((++counter))" \
        --repo "$GITHUB_REPOSITORY"
```

Setting `--repo` explicitly allows you to not check out the repository, if desired. When checked out, you can drop that parameter.